Make top-level types in Gatsby createSchemaCustomization non-nullable during GraphQL type generation
Top-level MarkdownRemark field in a graphql query in a Gatsby site cannot practically be null. But gatsby graphql typegen is generating it as nullable. It is annoying to have to account for nullability of a field that's never actually null.
Non-null operator ! inside of type definition in createSchemaCustomization works on only child fields, not on root fields. So, how can I make such top-level types non-nullable?
